# Community site, bad reputation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, social, community-site

Just created a site collection based on the out of the box community site template. Farm version is SP1 Mark 2 (15.0.4571.1502). Added a few members, had a few posts and replies.

Reputation and **community counters simply don't get updated**. I've tried re-activating the web scoped community feature. That updated some of the counters.

Maybe worth mentioning is that I created a subsite in the same site collection based on the same community site template. Here all reputation counters are refreshed as expected.

Do you have similar experiences? Any catches? Fixes?

Comment: Can you check the User Profile Service Application. I think there is something to be found there since the USP handles Social tags and notes.

Comment: Community site reputation counters are kept in the Content DB...

Answer (score 3):

`Discussion` content type seems to be very fragile.

Reputation mechanism started failing when I added the `Enterprise Keywords` column to this content type. While in this context, discussion counters where not updated and as soon as I removed the column, expected behavior came back.

Some other remarks: discussion counters will not decrease if the posts are removed... Re-activating the Community Site Feature will trigger recounting some of the counters...

Overall, disappointing experience, hopefully bugs will be addressed in future product updates.

Will just leave the info here, in case someone finds it useful.